# how to make a css text overflow animation

Tags: css

I have this right now http://codepen.io/capraruioan/pen/dXyyMp

```
.parent
  position: relative
  width: 300px
  border: 1px solid black
  margin-left: 40%
  height: 20px
  .child
    position: absolute
    min-width: 100%
    white-space: nowrap
    animation-name: bounceText
    animation-duration: 5s
    animation-direction: alternate
    animation-iteration-count: infinite
    animation-timing-function: linear
@keyframes bounceText {
    0% {
        left: 0
    }
    100% {
    right: 0%
      // left: -100%
    }
}
```

I want the text to bounce from left to right only if the width is > 100%

that's why i've put min-height: 100%
ideal would be to bounce from left: 0 to right: 0. But there is no animation if I do that..

can I do this with only CSS ? I don't want to use jquery

Comment: I have a viewport of 300px. and a text that can be more that 300px in width. in that case I want it to bounce inside the viewport. Your fix is just for the current text, but it won't work on larger texts

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really understood what you're asking but maybe is something like this?

```
.parent
  position: relative
  width: 450px
  border: 1px solid black
  margin-left: 34%
  height: 20px
  .child
    display: block
    position: absolute
    min-width: 100%
    white-space: nowrap
    animation-name: bounceText
    animation-duration: 2s
    animation-direction: alternate
    animation-iteration-count: infinite
    animation-timing-function: linear
@keyframes bounceText {
    0% {
        left: 0%
    }
    100% {
    left: 18%

    }
}
```